# What does the word host in a host microcontroller mean?

Tags: microcontroller, embedded, host

The MAX32664 family can communicate with several of Maxim’s optical sensor solutions (see table for details) delivering raw or calculated data, as required by the user application. This is achieved while also minimizing overall system power consumption. All versions interface to a host microcontroller through a fast-mode, slave I2C interface.

Comment: It means nothing without context, really. I guess by "host" they mean someone who actually gives a darn about collecting the sensor data? A sensor that nobody listens to fills no purpose.

Answer (score 1):

The *host* is interacting as the master in the I2C bus. He creates the clock and he adresses the sensors as slaves to read their data.